# Dynamodb: ValidationException: Query key condition not supported.

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to query like to Journalist table, I want all journalist that the author name start with 'Josefina".

This is the table attributes

```
var params = {
TableName : "Journalist",
KeySchema: [       
    { AttributeName: "author", KeyType: "HASH"},
    { AttributeName: "isShow", KeyType: "RANGE" }
],
AttributeDefinitions: [       
    { AttributeName: "author", AttributeType: "S"},
    { AttributeName: "isShow", AttributeType: "S" }
],
ProvisionedThroughput: {       
    ReadCapacityUnits: 100, 
    WriteCapacityUnits: 10
}
```

};

And this is the query that I try to do

```
const params = {
        TableName: "Journalist",
        KeyConditionExpression: "begins_with(author, :t)",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":t": "Josefina"
        }
    };
```

And I get this:

Failure { ValidationException: Query key condition not supported

I try in so many ways, I delete the table and create with other attributes, I create other keys and sort, by I get always similar errors.